# Animações não aparecem

Tags: html, jquery, css, animação

Boas pessoal, estou a tentar fazer umas animações em scroll, mas  não sei porquê mas não vejo animação nenhuma, as secções não fazem reveal À medida que vou fazendo scroll...

Html:

Adicionei a classe js--wp-1, js--wp-3, js--wp-4 nos elementos que queria animar.

CSS:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------- */
/* ANIMATIONS */
/* ---------------------------------------------- */


.js--wp-1,
.js--wp-3,
.js--wp-4{
   opacity: 0;                        
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-duration: 1s;
}


.js--wp-1.animated,
.js--wp-3.animated,
.js--wp-4.animated{                              
   opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
 /*Animations on scroll*/
        /*Animation 1*/
        $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {  /* Waypoint*/
            $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');  /*Select animationçao*/
        }, {
            offset: '40%'
         });




        /*Animation 3*/
        $('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction) { 
            $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
        }, {
            offset: '50%'
         });



        /*Animation 4*/
        $('.js--wp-4').waypoint(function(direction) { 
            $('.js--wp-4').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
        }, {
            offset: '50%'
         });
```

Obrigado pessoal!

PS: Estou a utilizar o animate.css para fazer estas animações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando as informações postadas na sua pergunta, o animate.css sozinho não tem ligação com o scroll e não entendi muito bem a sua tentativa de adicionar a detecção de scroll.

Porém, tenho uma alternativa bacana (e bem fácil de implementar) para o que você está tentando fazer, utilizando o wow.js. Que, inclusive, utiliza o animate.css para fazer a animação.

Segue o link:
[wow.js](https://wowjs.uk)

Qualquer dúvida, pode comentar.

Espero ter ajudado! :)